# Proving a function is bounded without using calculus

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

Question:

Show that  $ \ f\left(x\right)=\ \frac{\left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right|}{x^2+3}$ is bounded. Do not use calculus.

My attempt:

$ \frac{\left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right|}{x^2+3}=\ \frac{\left|x^2-1\right|}{x^2+3}\le \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+3},\ by\ triangle\ inequality\  $

I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't $|x^2|=x^2$?

Comment: Yes. What do I do from here?

Comment: $x^2+1 < x^2+3$

Comment: Hint: $x^2 + 1 \le x^2 + 3$.

Comment: So $ \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+3}<1\ $ ?

Comment: @RobertIsrael when do you think equality holds? Never?

Comment: equality doesn't hold right?

Comment: That is correct.  I could just as well have used $<$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just one more step:
$$
\frac{\left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right|}{x^2+3}=\ \frac{\left|x^2-1\right|}{x^2+3}\le \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+3} \le \frac{x^2+3}{x^2+3} = 1.
$$

Comment: Could I say $ \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+3}<1\ $ since $ x^2 +1 < x^2 + 3$?

Comment: Also , why did you use $ \le $? Shouldn't it be $ < $?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite fraction as $$\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+3} = \dfrac{x^2+3-2}{x^2+3} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{x^2+3}$$
and then
$$\dfrac{1}{3} \leqslant 1 - \dfrac{2}{x^2+3} < 1.$$